# Using php to check checkboxes based on past user preferences?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check checkboxes based on previous user preferences that are stored in a CSV, but it is only running checking the first index in the CSV and skipping the rest. In the following code below if I pass it a CSV of "Sports, Lowkey, Wine" I want it to check those three on page load but it is only checking Sports

```
$typeArray = array(
            "1" => "Sports",
            "2" => "College",
            "3" => "Pub",
            "4" => "Night Club",
            "5" => "Lowkey",
            "6" => "Wine",
            "7" => "Craft Beer",
        );
        $Sports="";
        $College="";
        $Pub="";
        $NightClub="";
        $Lowkey="";
        $Wine="";
        $CraftBeer="";
        $string = "Sports, Lowkey, Wine";
        $csv = str_getcsv($string, ", ");
        for($i=0; $i<count($csv); $i++){
            $index = array_search($csv[$i], $typeArray);
            if($index == 1){
                $Sports = "checked";
            }
            if($index == 2){
                $College = "checked";
            }
            if($index == 3){
                $Pub = "checked";
            }
            if($index == 4){
                $NightClub = "checked";
            }
            if($index == 5){
                $Lowkey = "checked";
            }
            if($index == 6){
                $Wine = "checked";
            }
            if($index == 7){
                $CraftBeer = "checked";
            }
            unset($index);
        }
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Type[1]\" value=\"Sports\"" . $Sports . ">Sports ";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Type[2]\" value=\"College\"" . $College . ">College ";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Type[3]\" value=\"Pub\"" . $Pub . ">Pub ";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Type[4]\" value=\"Night Club\"" . $NightClub . ">Night Club ";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Type[5]\" value=\"Lowkey\"" . $Lowkey . ">Lowkey<br> ";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Type[6]\" value=\"Wine\"" . $Wine . ">Wine ";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Type[7]\" value=\"Craft Beer\"" . $CraftBeer . ">Craft Beer<br> ";
```

Comment: could you post the cvs (or a representative sample of it)? oops. just saw you did....

Comment: @user3511578 I use a string CSV, this takes the string then makes it into an array $string = "Sports, Lowkey, Wine";
        $csv = str_getcsv($string, ", ");

Comment: Try changing `name=\"Type[1]\"` to `name=\"1\"` and do the same for the others. Because, I don't see anything related to `Type`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is called Type[] because this is for a bar web app that shows what kind of bar it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exchange this line
`$index = array_search($csv[$i], $typeArray);`

with this:

`$index = array_search(trim($csv[$i]), $typeArray);`

Answer (score 1):

When you do a var_dump of `$csv` you will notice that there is a space before `Lowkey` and `Wine`:

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(6) "Sports" 
    [1]=> string(7) " Lowkey" 
    [2]=> string(5) " Wine" 
}
```

So your `array_search` will fail.

According to the [manual](http://php.net/array_search), the `delimiter` in `str_get_csv` can be only one character. You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) or [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) instead.

```
$csv = explode(', ', $string);

// or 

$index = array_search(trim($csv[$i]), $typeArray);
```